# Equivalent to dlopen(None) in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-cffi

I am using Python CFFI and want to open a library where I can call `free` on some data I get back. In Linux and Mac, I put `free` in the cdefs and load a base C library with `dlopen(None)`.

```py
from cffi import FFI

header = """
    typedef struct {
      int32_t*     members;
    } container_t;

    void free(void *ptr);
"""

cdefs = FFI()
cdefs.cdef(header)
cdefs.set_source("_main", "")  # So that the header can be `include`d externally
lib = cdefs.dlopen(None)


def free_members(container) -> None:
    lib.free(container.members)
```

This fails on Windows with the well-documented error:

```
OSError: dlopen(None) cannot work on Windows for Python 3 (see http://bugs.python.org/issue23606)
```

What gives the equivalent behavior on Windows? I just want `free`, which should be available on any old DLL anywhere.

Comment: So the library you're using specifically says that the pointers it return should be freed with `free`? IMO this is a poor design, and the library should provide a symmetric interface with a function to release what object it allocated.

Comment: Try `cdefs.dlopen(ctypes.util.find_msvcrt())` or `cdefs.dlopen("msvcrt")`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It is more that my library says "If you want to create your own structs such that this library can take ownership of them, you need to allocate its members such that `free` will free them." And then everyone typically uses `malloc`. Is that not a good design?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the API approach with `ffi_builder.compile()`.  This lets you write portable C code like

```
ffi_builder.cdef(""" void free(void *); """)
ffi_builder.set_source("_main", "")
ffi_builder.compile()
```

and then you can use

```
from _main import lib, ffi
lib.free(p)
```

Trying to get the correct `free()` function is a complete mess on Windows, because it is not standard.  There are a number of libraries (and multiple versions of them) that each provide `malloc()` and `free()`, and of course if you mix the `malloc()` from one library with the `free()` from another, then everything explodes.  The solution I describe above should work if `compile()` happens to use the same compiler (and version!) as the one that was used to make your library.  In general, that's why it's a poor design on Windows to say "this function returns a pointer and you have to call `free()` yourself".